# How to create MySQL query to return records older than a predefined date in a separate table

Tags: mysql

I am in the process of creating a maintenance query for a MySQL table where I need to mark records as deletable (Update a column value from 0 to 1) based on a date field in the table.

Pretty simple but the problem I have is that the criteria to mark the record as deletable varies depending on the account ID (acc_id column).

For example, the table will have records from multiple accounts (acc_id field) and there is a separate accounts table that has a column (retention_age) that I need to use to determine whether a record can be marked as deletable.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM files 
 WHERE DATE(file_downloaded_date) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
   AND deleted = 0;
```

So for example, in the table with the records to update, there may be 100 records for acc_id = 1, 250 records for acc_id = 2 etc.... acc_id 1 is set to mark records as deletable after 14 days, acc_id 2 is set to mark as deletable after 30 days.

I'm trying to figure out if I can create an SQL query to do this all in one query or if I'll need to create a separate query for each account.

I'm thinking that if there would be a way to replace the '30' in INTERNAL 30 DAY, with the retention_age value for the acc_id of each record that would be the best way but I don't know how to do that or if that will even work.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) to get the respective account and the use its `retention_age` as the `INTERVAL`:

```sql
DELETE files FROM files
LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = files.acc_id
WHERE
    DATE(file_downloaded_date) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL accounts.retention_age DAY)
    AND deleted = 0
```

Comment: Just gave that a try and it seems to work as I need.